# How to prevent Safari from asking me on every single site if I want to allow plugins?

Tags: safari

Every single site I go to pops up an annoying message stating,

> Do you want to trust the website “EveryWebsite” to use the “Shockwave Flash” plug-in?

Every single time I click yes. Is there a way I can allow my plugins, that I choose to have installed and enabled in Safari, allowed for all websites?

NB Also, I noticed it doesn't pop up a notification for trusting it's own Quicktime plugin. Is there a place I can file an [antitrust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competition_law) lawsuit, I mean a bug report, on Apple's site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari Prefs > Security > [Internet Plug-ins] > Website Settings…

[image]

[image]